# Problemas al instalar SQL Server 2016 en Windows 10

Tags: sql-server, windows10, sql-server-2016

Llevo tiempo intentando instalar SQL Server, sucede un problema donde no me deja completar la instalación. Cada vez intento borrar y volver a instalar me produce los siguientes errores:

[image: Este es el error que se produce]

**Lo que dice el archivo log:**

> > Overall summary:   Final result:                  Error: vea los detalles a continuación   Exit code (Decimal):           -2068578302
> >     Start time:                    2017-03-02 17:32:04   End time:
> >     2017-03-02 18:05:46   Requested action:              Repair
>
> Setup completed with required actions for features. Troubleshooting
>   information for those features:   Next step for Polybase:        Use
>   la siguiente información para resolver el error e intente de nuevo el
>   proceso de instalación.   Next step for SQLEngine:       Use la
>   siguiente información para resolver el error e intente de nuevo el
>   proceso de instalación.   Next step for DQ:              Use la
>   siguiente información para resolver el error e intente de nuevo el
>   proceso de instalación.   Next step for FullText:        Use la
>   siguiente información para resolver el error e intente de nuevo el
>   proceso de instalación.   Next step for AdvancedAnalytics: Use la
>   siguiente información para resolver el error e intente de nuevo el
>   proceso de instalación.   Next step for Replication:     Use la
>   siguiente información para resolver el error e intente de nuevo el
>   proceso de instalación.   Next step for RS:              Use la
>   siguiente información para resolver el error e intente de nuevo el
>   proceso de instalación.
>
> Machine Properties:   Machine name:                  DIEGO-ULISES
>   Machine processor count:       4   OS version:
>   Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language (10.0.14393)   OS service
>   pack:                  OS region:                     España   OS
>   language:                   español (España, alfabetización
>   internacional)   OS architecture:               x64   Process
>   architecture:          64 bits   OS clustered:                  No
>
> Product features discovered:   Product              Instance
>   Instance ID                    Feature
>   Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 
>   Configured   SQL Server 2016      MSSQLSERVER
>   MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER            Servicios de Motor de base de datos
>   1033                 Enterprise Edition   13.0.1601.5     No
>   Sí           SQL Server 2016      MSSQLSERVER
>   MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER            Servicios de Motor de base de datos
>   3082                 Enterprise Edition   13.0.1601.5     No
>   Sí           SQL Server 2016      MSSQLSERVER
>   MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER            Replicación de SQL Server
>   1033                 Enterprise Edition   13.0.1601.5     No
>   Sí           SQL Server 2016      MSSQLSERVER
>   MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER            Replicación de SQL Server
>   3082                 Enterprise Edition   13.0.1601.5     No
>   Sí           SQL Server 2016      MSSQLSERVER
>   MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER            Extracciones de texto completo y
>   semánticas de búsqueda 1033                 Enterprise Edition
>   13.0.1601.5     No         Sí           SQL Server 2016      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER            Data Quality
>   Services                    1033                 Enterprise Edition
>   13.0.1601.5     No         Sí           SQL Server 2016      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER            Data Quality
>   Services                    3082                 Enterprise Edition
>   13.0.1601.5     No         Sí           SQL Server 2016      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER            Servicio de
>   consultas de PolyBase para datos externos 1033
>   Enterprise Edition   13.0.1601.5     No         Sí           SQL
>   Server 2016      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER            R
>   Services (En base de datos)            1033                 Enterprise
>   Edition   13.0.1601.5     No         Sí           SQL Server 2016
>   MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER            sql_inst_mr
>   1033                 Enterprise Edition   13.0.1601.5     No
>   Sí           SQL Server 2016      MSSQLSERVER
>   MSAS13.MSSQLSERVER             Analysis Services
>   1033                 Enterprise Edition   13.0.1728.2     No
>   Sí           SQL Server 2016      MSSQLSERVER
>   MSAS13.MSSQLSERVER             Analysis Services
>   3082                 Enterprise Edition   13.0.1728.2     No
>   Sí           SQL Server 2016      MSSQLSERVER
>   MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER             Reporting Services - Nativo
>   1033                                      13.0.1728.2     No
>   Sí           SQL Server 2016      MSSQLSERVER
>   MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER             Reporting Services - Nativo
>   3082                                      13.0.1728.2     No
>   Sí           SQL Server 2016
>   Conectividad con las herramientas de cliente 3082
>   Enterprise Edition   13.0.14500.10   No         Sí           SQL
>   Server 2016
>   Compatibilidad con versiones anteriores de las herramientas de cliente
>   3082                 Enterprise Edition   13.0.14500.10   No
>   Sí           SQL Server 2016
>   SDK de las herramientas de cliente       3082
>   Enterprise Edition   13.0.14500.10   No         Sí           SQL
>   Server 2016
>   Cliente de calidad de datos              3082
>   Enterprise Edition   13.0.1601.5     No         Sí           SQL
>   Server 2016
>   Integration Services                     3082
>   Enterprise Edition   13.0.1601.5     No         Sí           SQL
>   Server 2016
>   Reporting Services - SharePoint
>   13.0.1601.5     No         Sí           SQL Server 2016                                                          Master Data Services                     1033
>   Enterprise Edition   13.0.1728.2     No         Sí           SQL
>   Server 2016                                                          R
>   Server (independiente)                                      Enterprise
>   Edition   13.0.1728.2     No         Sí
>
> Package properties:   Description:                   Microsoft SQL
>   Server 2016    ProductName:                   SQL Server 2016   Type: 
>   RTM   Version:                       13   SPLevel:
>   0   Installation location:         F:\x64\setup\   Installation
>   edition:          Enterprise
>
> Configuración de entrada de usuario:   ACTION:
>   Repair   AGTDOMAINGROUP:                   AGTSVCACCOUNT:
>      AGTSVCPASSWORD:                   AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE: 
>   Manual   ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config   ASSVCACCOUNT:
>   NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService   ASSVCPASSWORD:
>      ASTELSVCACCT:                  NT Service\SSASTELEMETRY
>   ASTELSVCPASSWORD:                 ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
>   Automatic   CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                Manual   CLTSVCACCOUNT:
>   NT Service\SQL Server Distributed Replay Client   CLTSVCPASSWORD:
>      CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\130\Setup
>   Bootstrap\Log\20170302_173200\ConfigurationFile.ini   CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:
>   Manual   CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                NT Service\SQL Server
>   Distributed Replay Controller   CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               
>   ENU:                           false   EXTSVCACCOUNT:
>   NT Service\MSSQLLaunchpad   EXTSVCPASSWORD:                
>   FAILOVERCLUSTERGROUP:             FAILOVERCLUSTERNETWORKNAME:
>      FTSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher
>   FTSVCPASSWORD:                    HELP:
>   false   IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:      false   INDICATEPROGRESS:
>   false   INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER   ISSVCACCOUNT:
>   NT Service\MsDtsServer130   ISSVCPASSWORD:                 
>   ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic   ISTELSVCACCT:
>   NT Service\SSISTELEMETRY130   ISTELSVCPASSWORD:              
>   ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           Automatic   MRCACHEDIRECTORY:
>   QUIET:                         false   QUIETSIMPLE:
>   false   SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQLSERVER
>   SQLSVCPASSWORD:                   SQLTELSVCACCT:
>   NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY   SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:             
>   SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:          Automatic
>   SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false   UIMODE:
>   Normal   X86:                           false
>
> Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20170302_173200\ConfigurationFile.ini
>
> Detailed results:   Feature:                       Conectividad con
>   las herramientas de cliente   Status:                        Correcto
>
> Feature:                       SDK de las herramientas de cliente
>   Status:                        Correcto
>
> Feature:                       Compatibilidad con versiones
>   anteriores de las herramientas de cliente   Status:
>   Correcto
>
> Feature:                       Servicio de consultas de PolyBase
>   para datos externos   Status:                        Error: consulte
>   los registros para obtener detalles   Reason for failure:
>   Error en el proceso de instalación de la característica debido a un
>   error en una dependencia de la misma.   Next Step:
>   Use la siguiente información para resolver el error e intente de nuevo
>   el proceso de instalación.   Component name:
>   Características de instancia de los Servicios de motor de base de
>   datos de SQL Server   Component error code:          0x84B40002
>   Error description:             La característica
>   'SQL_Engine_Core_Inst' de SQL Server no tiene un estado de reparación
>   admitido, ya que nunca se configuró correctamente. Sólo las
>   características de instalaciones correctas se pueden reparar. Para
>   continuar, quite la característica especificada.   Error help link:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.1728.2&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402
>
> Feature:                       Servicios de Motor de base de datos
>   Status:                        Error: consulte los registros para
>   obtener detalles   Reason for failure:            Error durante el
>   proceso de instalación de la característica.   Next Step:
>   Use la siguiente información para resolver el error e intente de nuevo
>   el proceso de instalación.   Component name:
>   Características de instancia de los Servicios de motor de base de
>   datos de SQL Server   Component error code:          0x84B40002
>   Error description:             La característica
>   'SQL_Engine_Core_Inst' de SQL Server no tiene un estado de reparación
>   admitido, ya que nunca se configuró correctamente. Sólo las
>   características de instalaciones correctas se pueden reparar. Para
>   continuar, quite la característica especificada.   Error help link:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.1728.2&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402
>
> Feature:                       Data Quality Services   Status:
>   Error: consulte los registros para obtener detalles   Reason for
>   failure:            Error en el proceso de instalación de la
>   característica debido a un error en una dependencia de la misma.
>   Next Step:                     Use la siguiente información para
>   resolver el error e intente de nuevo el proceso de instalación.
>   Component name:                Características de instancia de los
>   Servicios de motor de base de datos de SQL Server   Component error
>   code:          0x84B40002   Error description:             La
>   característica 'SQL_Engine_Core_Inst' de SQL Server no tiene un estado
>   de reparación admitido, ya que nunca se configuró correctamente. Sólo
>   las características de instalaciones correctas se pueden reparar. Para
>   continuar, quite la característica especificada.   Error help link:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.1728.2&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402
>
> Feature:                       Extracciones de texto completo y
>   semánticas de búsqueda   Status:                        Error:
>   consulte los registros para obtener detalles   Reason for failure:
>   Error en el proceso de instalación de la característica debido a un
>   error en una dependencia de la misma.   Next Step:
>   Use la siguiente información para resolver el error e intente de nuevo
>   el proceso de instalación.   Component name:
>   Características de instancia de los Servicios de motor de base de
>   datos de SQL Server   Component error code:          0x84B40002
>   Error description:             La característica
>   'SQL_Engine_Core_Inst' de SQL Server no tiene un estado de reparación
>   admitido, ya que nunca se configuró correctamente. Sólo las
>   características de instalaciones correctas se pueden reparar. Para
>   continuar, quite la característica especificada.   Error help link:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.1728.2&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402
>
> Feature:                       R Services (En base de datos)
>   Status:                        Error: consulte los registros para
>   obtener detalles   Reason for failure:            Error en el proceso
>   de instalación de la característica debido a un error en una
>   dependencia de la misma.   Next Step:                     Use la
>   siguiente información para resolver el error e intente de nuevo el
>   proceso de instalación.   Component name:
>   Características de instancia de los Servicios de motor de base de
>   datos de SQL Server   Component error code:          0x84B40002
>   Error description:             La característica
>   'SQL_Engine_Core_Inst' de SQL Server no tiene un estado de reparación
>   admitido, ya que nunca se configuró correctamente. Sólo las
>   características de instalaciones correctas se pueden reparar. Para
>   continuar, quite la característica especificada.   Error help link:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.1728.2&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402
>
> Feature:                       Replicación de SQL Server   Status:
>   Error: consulte los registros para obtener detalles   Reason for
>   failure:            Error en el proceso de instalación de la
>   característica debido a un error en una dependencia de la misma.
>   Next Step:                     Use la siguiente información para
>   resolver el error e intente de nuevo el proceso de instalación.
>   Component name:                Características de instancia de los
>   Servicios de motor de base de datos de SQL Server   Component error
>   code:          0x84B40002   Error description:             La
>   característica 'SQL_Engine_Core_Inst' de SQL Server no tiene un estado
>   de reparación admitido, ya que nunca se configuró correctamente. Sólo
>   las características de instalaciones correctas se pueden reparar. Para
>   continuar, quite la característica especificada.   Error help link:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.1728.2&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402
>
> Feature:                       Master Data Services   Status:
>   Correcto
>
> Feature:                       Distributed Replay Client
>
> Status:                        Correcto
>
> Feature:                       Distributed Replay Controller
>   Status:                        Correcto
>
> Feature:                       Integration Services   Status:
>   Correcto
>
> Feature:                       Cliente de calidad de datos   Status:
>   Correcto
>
> Feature:                       Reporting Services - Nativo   Status:
>   Error: consulte los registros para obtener detalles   Reason for
>   failure:            Error durante el proceso de instalación de la
>   característica.   Next Step:                     Use la siguiente
>   información para resolver el error e intente de nuevo el proceso de
>   instalación.   Component name:                SQL Server Reporting
>   Services   Component error code:          0x84B40002   Error
>   description:             La característica 'RS_Server_Adv' de SQL
>   Server no tiene un estado de reparación admitido, ya que nunca se
>   configuró correctamente. Sólo las características de instalaciones
>   correctas se pueden reparar. Para continuar, quite la característica
>   especificada.   Error help link:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.1728.2&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402&EvtType=0x2841E06E%401204%402
>
> Feature:                       Analysis Services   Status:
>   Correcto
>
> Feature:                       Reporting Services - SharePoint
>   Status:                        Correcto
>
> Feature:                       Complemento de Reporting Services
>   para productos de SharePoint   Status:                        Correcto
>
> Feature:                       SQL Browser   Status:
>   Correcto
>
> Feature:                       Componentes de la documentación
>   Status:                        Correcto
>
> Feature:                       Objeto de escritura de SQL   Status: 
>   Correcto
>
> Feature:                       Conectividad de cliente SQL   Status:
>   Correcto
>
> Feature:                       SDK de conectividad de cliente SQL
>   Status:                        Correcto
>
> Feature:                       R Server (independiente)   Status:
>   Correcto
>
> Feature:                       Archivos auxiliares del programa de
>   configuración   Status:                        Correcto
>
> Rules with failures:
>
> Global rules:
>
> There are no scenario-specific rules.
>
> Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\Setup
>   Bootstrap\Log\20170302_173200\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
>
> Se encontraron las siguientes advertencias al establecer la
>   configuración en SQL Server. Faltaba la configuración / de estos
>   recursos o no era válida. Se usaron los valores predeterminados para
>   recrear los recursos que faltaban. Revíselos para asegurarse de que no
>   es necesaria una personalización adicional en las aplicaciones:
>
> No se encontró el servicio SQL Server Browser en el sistema. El
>   programa de configuración configurará su tipo de inicio como
>   'Deshabilitado'. No se encontró el servicio SQL Server Browser en el
>   sistema. El programa de configuración configurará su tipo de inicio
>   como 'Deshabilitado'. No se encontró el servicio SQL Server Browser en
>   el sistema. El programa de configuración configurará su tipo de inicio
>   como 'Deshabilitado'.

Comment: ¿Revisaste [Requisitos de hardware y software para instalar SQL Server 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms143506.aspx)?

Comment: De casualidad quieres instalar la versión Enterprise del SQL Server 2016?

Comment: Intentado instalar todas las versiones ... y todas fallan, mi pc tiene todos los requisitos..

Comment: Recuerdo dolores de cabeza parecidos al tuyo, en el pasado, cuando intentaba instalar SQL Server. Uno de los problemas es que a veces se quedan instalaciones viejas en tu equipo y eso (hablo de unos 10 años atrás) era terrible, no me dejaba instalar las nuevas. No sé si SQL Server y Windows han evolucionado en ese sentido... Trata de borrar todo vestigio de una instalación antigua de SQL Server, aunque se trate de otras versiones anteriores o posteriores. Creo que SQL Server ha sido para mi el software más difícil de instalar y configurar. Saludos y mucho ánimo.

Comment: la solucion: prepara un usb arrancable con la ultima version de windows 10 directamente de la web de microsoft, copia tu licencia en un papel, reformatea tu computadora, espera todo el proceso, reinstala los drivers, luego instala sql server, claro todo esto va a funcionar si tienes la version pro, la version home es para editar word y mirar paginas web, la version pro es para programar, Estos errores que te salen es por actualizar de w8 a w10

Answer (score 1):

Revisado los prerrequisitos y la información que brindas de tu SO `Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single` **no vas a poder instalar** SQL Server Enterprise (13.0.1601.5). Para dicha edición es necesario un `Windows Server 2012 Standard` como mínimo para poder instalarlo.

Para la versión de tu SO te recomiendo instalar `SQL Server Developer`que tiene "casi la misma" característica que `SQL Server Enterprise`.

Considera en tu instalación la [Edición SQL Server 2016 SP1 Developer](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/sql-server/sql-server-editions-developers)

**Recuerda:**

> SQL Server 2016 (13.0.1601.5) es una versión RTM.
>
> SQL Server 2016 SP1 (13.0.4001.0 o 13.1.4001.0) que soluciona problemas con la edición anterior.

---

[- Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx)

[- Microsoft SQL Server Version List](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.pe/)

Comment: intentado instalar Sql Server 2000 hasta Sql Server 2016 ninguno se puede y mi computadora cumple todos los requisitos, la única forma que se a completado la instalación es una maquina virtual... nose que tendría que eliminar para poder realizar la operación de manera exitosa...

Comment: @Diego ¿Cuál es el SO donde lo instalaste? ¿Llegaste a probar con el SQL Developer SP1? =)

Comment: La maquina virtual es Windows 10 y si ya antes intente con Sql Developer SP1

Comment: u_u @Diego entonces hay que refutarle a los [requisitos expuestos en la página de  Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx#TOP_Principal) y decir que **si se puede**. Por lo general recomiendo el Developer. Suerte

Comment: No quiero hacer una respuesta pero ocupo estos comentarios. Lo que yo hice fue meter uno por uno SO en una máquina virtual, y ahí instalar el SQL Server 2016, y donde jaló fue en Windows 8.1, Aparte tuve que instalar varios archivos Ej: KB19294. Por mi especialidad de carrera tuve que desinstalar Windows 10 e instalar el 8.1 a fuerza. Mi máquina no corría por la arquitectura en windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos Siempre se ha podido, no deberías de tener ningún problema en que idioma esta SQL Server? Español por lo que veo recuerda que debes de estar en Windows con idioma español de España.

Ahora bien veo que quieres instalar R, aunque teóricamente SQL Server ya no usa .NET 3.5 R y otras cuestiones si lo usan, a la vez instala de antemano Java para evitar problemas.

Si tienes problemas en tu pc y ya hiciste varias instalaciones borra o renombra la carpeta de bootstrap en el directorio de SQL Server.